# Does the C# compiler hoist variable declarations out of methods called within loops?

Tags: c#, c#-4.0, for-loop, compiler-construction, system.reflection

I have a method that calls a helper method from within a `for` loop. The helper method contains a relatively expensive variable declaration and definition that involves reflection (see below.) I'm wondering if the compiler can be counted on to inline the method call and hoist the declaration and definition out of the loop, or if I need to refactor the method in order to guarantee that the definition statement isn't executed with each iteration.

```
private class1[] BuildClass1ArrayFromTestData()
{
    var class1Count = int.Parse(testContextInstance.DataRow["class1[]"].ToString());
    var class1s = new List<class1>(class1Count);

    for (var c = 0; c < class1Count; c++)
    {
        class1s.Add(BuildClass1FromTestData(string.Format("class1[{0}]", c)));
    }

    return class1s.ToArray();
}

private class1 BuildClass1FromTestData(string testContextName)
{
    DataColumnCollection columns = testContextInstance.DataRow.Table.Columns;
    var class1Fields = typeof(class1).GetFields();

    var class1Object = new class1();

    foreach (var field in class1Fields)
    {
        var objectContextName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", testContextName, field.Name);

        if (!columns.Contains(objectContextName))
            continue;

        // Assume that all fields are of type "string" for simplicity
        field.SetValue(
            class1Object,      
            testContextInstance.DataRow[objectContextName].ToString()
            );
    }

    return class1Object;
}
```

**Update:**

Here is the alternative I'm envisioning, for clarification purposes:

```
private class1[] BuildClass1ArrayFromTestData()
{
    var class1Count = int.Parse(testContextInstance.DataRow["class1[]"].ToString());
    var class1s = new List<class1>(class1Count);

    // Moved from BuildClass1FromTestData()
    DataColumnCollection columns = testContextInstance.DataRow.Table.Columns;
    var class1Fields = typeof(class1).GetFields();

    for (var c = 0; c < class1Count; c++)
    {
        class1s.Add(BuildClass1FromTestData(string.Format("class1[{0}]", c)), columns, class1Fields);
    }

    return class1s.ToArray();
}

private class1 BuildClass1FromTestData(string testContextName, DataColumnCollection columns, FieldInfo[] class1Fields)
{
    var class1Object = new class1();

    foreach (var field in class1Fields)
    {
        var objectContextName = string.Format("{0}.{1}", testContextName, field.Name);

        if (!columns.Contains(objectContextName))
            continue;

        // Assume that all fields are of type "string" for simplicity
        field.SetValue(
            class1Object,      
            testContextInstance.DataRow[objectContextName].ToString()
            );
    }

    return class1Object;
}
```

Comment: I don't understand what part of your loop you think is expensive.  Your variable declaration is simply concatenating a string...  (and the assignment via reflection obviously requires the loop)

Comment: Also, I strongly suggest that you not worry too much about performance problems until you know that you have a performance problem. Otherwise, you're likely to spend time fixing the wrong problem, and leaving the real problem unaddressed.

Comment: @Kirk Woll
It's lines 1 and 2 of the BuildClass1FromTestData() method that strike me as expensive, considering that they don't change with each iteration of the loop in the calling code.

Comment: (1) is not expensive as it is just setting a local variable to point to information already in memory. (2) is not really expensive because that information is already available because you're using `typeof` which is basically a static lookup at compile time and the Fields are already available in a dictionary somewhere.

Answer (score 1):

There are no expensive variable declarations in C#.  In fact, MSIL doesn't even distinguish between variables declared inside a loop vs outside, they are all just local variables of the method (naturally there is a distinction between variables in the looping method and variables in the helper method).

Initialization might be expensive, but moving it outside the loop would significantly change the behavior of your code.

Comment: The logic I am considering moving out of helper method and prior to the loop in the calling method includes the retrieval of the Columns collection of the data table class and the retrieval of the fields of the type. Both of those operations will return the same information in each iteration, so I'm not sure how this refactoring will change the behavior of the code.

Comment: @DanielArant: Sounds like a worthwhile change, but that has nothing to do with where the variable is declared.  As a general rule, caching reflection lookups is a big benefit, because neither .NET nor the JIT will collapse repeated calls to `GetFields()`.

Answer (score 0):

The compiler won't do such thing, because it wouldn't be an optimization, but it would change the meaning of your code. Calling a function once is not the same thing as calling it multiple times, and the compiler is only allowed changes that don't alter the effects of the program when observed from the same thread. It cannot detect whether the function is *pure* or not.

As a side note, the compiler won't even inline function calls. It's the job of the JIT.

Comment: Makes sense. _I_ may know that a method will return the same value(s) with each iteration, but neither the compiler nor the JIT compiler can know that.

Comment: @DanielArant: The JIT compiler might well be able to figure that out, not intentionally, but if it performs common subexpression elimination and expression hoisting after inlining.